# How do I generate the sequence "\e[Z" in a terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, escape-characters

It is bound to `menu-complete` in GNU readline.

```
$ bind -p|grep menu
"\e[Z": menu-complete
# menu-complete-backward (not bound)
# old-menu-complete (not bound)
```

I think it's `Meta-`something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo) database for your terminal for the key that sends this escape sequence. The [`infocmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/infocmp) command dumps the terminfo entry for the current terminal.

```
$ infocmp | grep -oE ' k[[:alpha:]]+=\\E\[Z,'
 kcbt=\E[Z,
```

The [terminfo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) man page explains what `cbt` is the abbreviation of. (It also gives an example which corresponds to most terminals out there.)

```
$ man 5 terminfo | grep -w kcbt
       key_btab                      kcbt       kB        back-tab key
             kbs=^H, kcbt=\E[Z, kcub1=\E[D, kcud1=\E[B,
```

So you have it: `\e[Z` is backtab, i.e. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (on most terminals).